# stddev_samp changes value when created as a view

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, standard-deviation

Why does when I put my select query as it is, it works well? so here is my query

```
SELECT
            AVG(total_score) AS AVGtotal_Score,
            STDDEV_SAMP(total_score) AS STDDEV_SAMPtotal_score,
            AVG(Total_Answer_Time) AS AVGTotal_Answer_Time,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Answer_Time) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Answer_Time,
            AVG(Total_Hint) AS AVGTotal_Hint,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Hint) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Hint,
            AVG(Total_Hint_Time) AS AVGTotal_Hint_Time,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Hint_Time) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Hint_Time
        FROM
            average_pivot
```

and here is the output:
[z values image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d8J9.png)

and when I try to put it in a view like this:

```
create view ave_temp_z_table as (SELECT
            AVG(total_score) AS AVGtotal_Score,
            STDDEV_SAMP(total_score) AS STDDEV_SAMPtotal_score,
            AVG(Total_Answer_Time) AS AVGTotal_Answer_Time,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Answer_Time) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Answer_Time,
            AVG(Total_Hint) AS AVGTotal_Hint,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Hint) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Hint,
            AVG(Total_Hint_Time) AS AVGTotal_Hint_Time,
            STDDEV_SAMP(Total_Hint_Time) AS STDDEV_SAMPTotal_Hint_Time
        FROM
            average_pivot);
```

the output of the stddev_samp changes.. The output of the view is this
[z values as a view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6v6Y4.png)

Comment: Could the straight SQL and the view SQL be using different samples in the _SAMP functions?

Comment: Nope, it accesses the same table, however, i found threads regarding the bug in the mysql. That whenever the stddev_samp was used in a view, it changes(?) to stddev. I think that is the reason, because i tried to compute for the stddev value, and it has given me the exact answer like the one i used for my view :(